# How to get parent's element offset in javascript with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
console.dir(element[0].parentElement)
console.dir(element[0].parentElement.offsetTop)
```

I want to get parent's element offset in angularjs.

I try to get information about parentElement.

First row about parentElement has offsetTop like 385.

But when I check parentElement.offsetTop like second row, it return only 0.

I try to using parentElement.getBoundingClientRect(), but it return 0, too.

How cant I get parent's element offset?

Comment: Where u put ur code? if u put it in a directive's link function, then the element and its parentElement may not be properly rendered when u attempt to get its bounds.

Comment: what is it you are trying to accomplish here?  angular generally operates on the Data, not the DOM;  it is very rare that the location of an item on screen is relevant to any angular logic.

Comment: This isn't angular-specific. If you're just trying to get a parent element, I recommend using jqeruy `$(element).parent()` If you are using a `directive` like @MMhunter mentioned, you should show us that code

Comment: @Clasies I want to get postion in splitter. [purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330677/how-to-dynamically-reload-directive-template-with-angular-ui-layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u put ur code in a link function AND the size or position of element's parentElement depends on how you render your html based on scope variable, u are not able to get the correct offsetTop in the link function directly.

Will u try the following way by getting it after current angular digest:

```
scope.$evalAsync(function(){
    console.log(element[0].parentElement.offsetTop);
})
```

Check if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using jquery to get the offset of a parent (I will also create an example of how to do this with a custom attribute directive in angular shortly. Here is a quick example:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var element = $('#mydiv');
var parentOffset = $(element).offset();
console.log(parentOffset);
```

**ANGULAR**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
<head runat="server">

    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        <div parent-offset>Test</div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp', [])

    .controller('myController', function ($scope) {

    })
    .directive('parentOffset', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                console.log(element.parent().offset());
            }
        }
    })

}());
```

Comment: I face the same problem, too. It's parent offset return always 0.

Comment: Should it be 0? .offset returns the coordinates relative the document. Maybe you need `.position()` instead? http://api.jquery.com/position/